# Hit to retrieve `state` and `nonce` from the response using regular expression in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have the following response,

```
code\u0026state=cb26ce12-f536-4461-b3ef-339ad846b03e\u0026response_mode=form_post\u0026nonce=75025267-ea92-46b3-8b90-8b78c11d6071\u0026uaid=360422b0f1004bb3a03423ae2f2afb1e\u0026msproxy=1\u0026issuer=mso\u0026tenant=common\u0026ui_locales=en-US\u0026signup=1\u0026lw=1\u0026fl=easi2","urlMsaLogout":"https://login.live.com/logout.srf?iframed_by=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com","urlOtherIdpForget":"https://login.live.com/forgetme.srf?iframed_by=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com","showCantAccessAccountLink":true,"urlGitHubFed":"https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=b4f99d51-f6d7-41ce-a058-5b7834afa240\u0026scope=openid\u0026redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fsprnt-app05.perceptive.cloud%2fsprint04-webimpact%2fapplication%2fstart.do\u0026response_type=code\u0026state=cb26ce12-f536-4461-b3ef-339ad846b03e\u00
```

want to retrieve `nonce` and `state` using the regex extractor.

I have tried with `.*state=(.*).*`  but not working specially with the escape character `\u0026`, any clue how to retrieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `state=(.+?)\\u0026` ?

[image]

[Meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) need to be escaped with another backslash

Also if you have hard time coming up with a proper regular expression you can always use [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) instead, it's much easier to use and it works faster.

[image]